# Why doesn't using an interaction/effect modification term give the same results as subsetting the data?

Tags: interaction, regression-coefficients

I'm interested in the effect of continuous variable A at the two different levels of categorical variable B.
I had thought that the following approach would give the same estimates for the effect of A:
Y = A + B + A*B
Y = A (in data where B=0)
Y = A (in data where B=1)

For example, here is a CoxPH model in R with some made up data:

```
time    <- c(2, 5, 1, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 7, 2, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
             10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
status  <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
A       <- c(19, 42, 28, 17, 69, 32, 44, 36, 27, 45, 9, 22, 18, 24, 9, 30, 26, 
             29, 14, 36, 19, 6, 11, 16, 20, 18, 5, 15, 22, 13)
B       <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
             0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
df      <- data.frame(time, status, A, B)
df$B    <- factor(B)

cx1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ A + B + A*B, df)
cx1

cx2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ A, df[df$B==0, ])
cx2

cx3 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ A, df[df$B==1, ])
cx3
```

And the output:

```
cx1
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ A + B + A * B, data = df)
       coef exp(coef) se(coef)    z     p
A    0.0571    1.0588   0.0198 2.88 0.004
B1   0.4712    1.6019   1.4518 0.32 0.746
A:B1 0.0132    1.0133   0.0468 0.28 0.779

cx2
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ A, data = df[df$B == 0, ])
    coef exp(coef) se(coef)    z     p
A 0.0534    1.0549   0.0201 2.65 0.008

cx3
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ A, data = df[df$B == 1, ])
    coef exp(coef) se(coef)    z    p
A 0.0632    1.0652   0.0444 1.42 0.15
```

I thought that the coefficient for A in cx1 (0.0571) would the same as the coefficient for A in cx2 (0.0534) as they both estimate the effect of A when B=0.  Similarly, when B=1, I thought that the estimate of A in cx1 (0.0571 + 0.0132 = 0.0703) would be the same as the estimate of A in cx3 (0.0632).

Any thoughts on where I've gone wrong in my thinking / programming would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try it on the linear model to see if your idea is correct by simulation.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. Yep the three linear models (using lm() in R) give me the coefficient values I expect. Hmmm, why doesn't coxph()?

Comment: try generalized linear model, for example, Poisson with log link, or logistic with logit link.

Comment: Yes, using glm() with poisson or binomial family also give me the coefficient values I expect (ie the same values whether I use an interaction term or subset the data). But I need to use coxph as I'm doing survival analysis and I've two problems: 1) I don't understand why the two methods (interaction or subsetting) give different results, 2) So I'm not sure which method gives me the best estimates of the effect of A at each level of B

Comment: Your reasoning is correct for FULL parametric model. Cox proportional hazard model is semi-parametric model, so your reasoning is failed. For model selection, I prefer the one large model with interaction over the two small models. But model selection is art, not science.

Comment: Ah, so the differences are due to different unspecified baseline hazards for B=0 and B=1 in the subset models, compared with a common unspecified baseline hazard for the full model. I see that if I include an interaction term and stratify by B ('coxph(Surv(time, status) ~  A * B - B + strata(B), df)') i get the same results as the subset models.  The "unspecified baseline hazard" always makes me slightly uneasy, as I don't think I fully understand it

Comment: In the process of the estimating, the conditional likelihood is evaluated when an event happens. When you fit model with A and B together, there are more events then any of the two smaller models. Therefore you get the different results. The model you give above seems to force the algorithm to work on the all events in A and B (I am not familiar with R), so get the same results.